# How to to isolate data in DB

Tags: database, view, schema

I have a table structured like this:

```
ProjectID | Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | ...
------------------------------------------
1         | aaa    | aaa    | aaa    | ...
------------------------------------------
2         | aaa    | aaa    | aaa    | ...
------------------------------------------
3         | aaa    | aaa    | aaa    | ...
------------------------------------------
1         | aaa    | aaa    | aaa    | ...
------------------------------------------
1         | aaa    | aaa    | aaa    | ...
------------------------------------------
2         | aaa    | aaa    | aaa    | ...
```

and some external systems that need to access this table to read data and write back one value at the and of the process.

The problem is that each external system will have to access only data related to his project, I.E.:

- System 1 -> ProjectID = 2
- System 2 -> ProjectID = 3
- System 3 -> ProjectID = 1

I'd like to keep this data separated to avoid errors because these systems will be developed externally from our application and I can't assume that they will use only their data.

I came across two solutions:

1. Create a table for each ProjectID in a different DB schema, and give to every external system only the credentials to access their table.
2. Create an updateable view for each ProjectID that extracts data only for a specific project, and give to every external system only the credentials to access their view.

Any other ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What database system are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if my other answer about an API won't work for you, then the appropriate way of handling this securely is to have a complete separation of the data. Don't intermix rows or store anything in the same table (or preferably database).

I would create a client-specific database and give each external system only access to that database.

Do you have a requirement to combine the data at some point? If so, you would lose key integrity, since you would have the same PKs (mostly) in each database table.

If you do need to combine the data, and a multi-column key is not an option, then an updateable view is really your only option so that you can keep that integrity.

Comment: Yes, I need to combine data, so maybe an updateable view is the only viable solution...

Comment: Maybe so. I would still probably just create a view that encompasses all those databases/tables, and would consider multiple columns as the key.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to develop an API that does all the interaction with your database, if you have multiple projects interacting with it. Keep your sanity, your sleep schedule, and your data integrity in tact. Don't solve this in the database layer.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't. This is a prerequisite of the external systems, so I can't do anything about that... :( But I second your answer, it would be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Just some stream of conscisousness...

I'm struggling with a similar problem.  my current solution is that i have 1 set of the tables but each record has a column referencing the OrganizationID.  my external program then appends in the SQL Select... Where...and User.OrganizationID = table.OrganizationID.

when a person, head of the parent org, views the data, i don't append the sql so they can see the data as it spans across all the child orgs.

This solution isn't much different then the update-able view (except that i have an application handling it).  I am also looking for a better solution since some of my data may span several Orgs that should interact with each others data (e.g. Project1 and Project2 can interact with each others data but Project 3 is isolated, and Project 4 can see it all)